# Alter Microsoft Access Column from MEMO to TEXT(255)

Tags: sql, ms-access, alter-table

I'm trying to alter a Microsoft Access Column from `MEMO` to `TEXT(255)`. Some of the records in my field exceed the 255 character limit. When I try:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyField TEXT(255)
```

I get an error because the text field can't support more than 255 characters. I've also tried:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN LEFT(MyField, 255) TEXT(255)
```

to get the first 255 characters, but that syntax isn't correct. Is there another way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in two steps:

```
update MyTable set MyField = LEFT(MyField, 255):

ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyField TEXT(255);
```

Comment: This should work. But beware, you may loose some characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can run an update statement first to do the truncation:

```
Update MyTable Set MyField = Left(MyField, 255);
```

Then alter the column length.

Comment: Seven seconds too late :-)